# Hago una autosuma de campos, pero no muestra el valor en textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

¿Qué puede estar mal formulado en mi funcion?

```js
$(function() {
  $('#sumAll').Keydown(function() {
    var add = 0;
    $('.cl').each(function() {
      add += Number($(this).val());
    });
    $('#sumAll').text(+ add);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
  <title>Sum TextBox values</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input id="Text1" class="cl" type="text" /><br />
  <input id="Text2" class="cl" type="text" /><br />
  <input id="Text3" class="cl" type="text" /><br />  
  <input id="sumAll" type="text" value="" /><br />
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: por que ocupas KeyDown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no entiendo porque ocupas el evento `keydown`, cuando este lo que hace es que si el usuario escribe en un input ahi recien es llamado el evento. Yo te recomendaria que si quieres hacer una "autosuma" juegues con el evento `onChange`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
  function suma() {
      var add = 0;
      $('.cl').each(function() {
          if (!isNaN($(this).val())) {
              add += Number($(this).val());
          }
      });
      $('#sumAll').val(add);
  };
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input id="Text1" class="cl" type="text" onChange="suma();" />
  <br />
  <input id="Text2" class="cl" type="text" onChange="suma();" />
  <br />
  <input id="Text3" class="cl" type="text" onChange="suma();" />
  <br />
  <input id="sumAll" type="text" value="" />
  <br />
</body>

</html>
```

Esto lo que hace es mientras cambien los valors de tus inputs los va sumando pero verifica que el contenido de cada uno sea un numero.

Comment: gracias, sioesi me sirvio la funcion hace lo que necesito (suma automatica) ahora necesito aplicar esta funcion a mi vista razor MVC.

Comment: Ahi si que me mataste ya que no conozco razor jajajaj, pero de seguro si haces una pregunta te ayudaran en el foro! Aunque te recomiendo que antes de que hagas una pregunta, puedas intentarlo por tus propios medios! asi te ayudaran mas rapido

Comment: ¿en caso de no querer sumar los campos sino multiplicar dos de ellos digamos text1 * text2 = sumAll solo tendría que cambiar esta linea?

Comment: add += Number($(this).val());

Comment: Ten en cuenta que esa linea recorre todos los input que tengan cl como clase, si quieres multiplicar solo dos, basta con que los llames por sus id y los multipliques, no hay necesidad de recorrerlos